# Pointers of Array in C

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

```
#include <stdio.h>

void main()
{
 int a[]={1,2,3,4};

 printf("%u %u ",a ,&a);           //a
 printf("%d %d ", *a ,*&a);        //b
}
```

In ath line the output of `a` and `&a` are same address but in bth line `*&a` does not give me the answer as `1`.

I know that `&a` means pointer to array of integers but as the address is same, it should print `1` right?

Comment: Read section 6 of the [comp.lang.c](http://www.c-faq.com/). And `void main()` should be `int main(void)`. And you're missing `#include <stdio.h>`.

Comment: Using `%u` in `printf` to print pointer values is undefined behavior (and it can easily lead to meaningless results in practice). There's `%p` specifically for printing pointers. And you should convert pointers to `void *` before sending them to `printf`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`a` decays to the pointer to the first element of the array.
`&a` is the pointer to the array of 4 `int`s.

Even though the numerical values of the two pointers are the same, the pointers are not of the same type.

Type of `a` (after it decays to a pointer) is `int*`.
Type of `&a` is a pointer to an array of 4 `int`s - `int (*)[4]`.

Type of `*a` is an `int`.
Type of `*&a` is an array of 4 ints - `int [4]`, which decays to the pointer to the first element in your expression.

The call

```
printf("%d %d ", *a ,*&a);
```

is equivalent to:

```
printf("%d %d ", *a , a);
```

BTW, You should use `%p` for pointers. Otherwise, you invoke undefined behavior. Increase the warning level of your compiler to avoid making such errors.

Answer (score 1):

Taking a simpler version of your code as follows:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void main()
{
 int a[]={1,2,3,4};

 printf("%d %d ", *a ,*&a);        //b
}
```

If I compile that code I get this warnings:

```
test1.c
D:\Temp\test1.c(7): warning C4477: 
    'printf' : format string '%d' requires an argument of type 'int', but variadic 
               argument 2 has type 'int *'
Microsoft (R) Incremental Linker Version 14.00.23506.0
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.
```

That warning message gives you the reason why this is not working as you expect.

Now I can change that code to remove those warnings and I end up with code like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void main()
{
 int a[]={1,2,3,4};

 int (*p)[4] = &a;

 printf("\n%u %u ", *a ,*p[0]);        //b
}
```

That code clean compiles and when it is run you get the expected output:

```
1 1
```

Answer (score 0):

The latest draft of the C standard suggests that

> If the operand is the result of a unary * operator,
>   **neither that operator nor the & operator is evaluated** and the result is **as if both were omitted**...

However, the above paragraph refers to the case when it's **&***, not ***&**. Try to think of it this way:

```
  &a   // pointer to array[4] of integers
*(&a)  // array[4] of integers
------------------------------------------
   a   // array[4] of integers
```

Note that **the operator * removes single layer of pointers**. Therefore, `*(&a)` is identical to `a` *semantically*. In this case, `a` is converted to an expression with the type `pointer to an integer`, because another paragraph suggests that

> Except when it is the operand of the sizeof operator, the _Alignof operator, or the unary & operator, or is a string literal used to initialize an array, **an expression that has type ‘‘array of type’’ is converted to an expression with type ‘‘pointer to type’’ that points to the initial element of the array object** and is not an lvalue...

In conclusion, the fact that the address of `a` (not the element inside) is printed is natural.

Answer (score 0):

Please do one more thing in your code:

`printf("%u %u ",a+1 ,&a+1);           //a1`